# Finding a homotopy function to show that two circles are homotopic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{a\}$

Tags: general-topology

If I have two counterclockwise circles in $\mathbb{C}$ that both have some point $a$ in their interior, how can I find a homotopy function to show that one is homotopic to the other?

Comment: Radial projection from $a$ will do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, I do not have it in my notes.

Comment: Draw a ray outwards from $a$ at any angle. How many times does that line cross each circle?

Comment: (What @DanRust said.)

Comment: It would be twice since its on the interior of both, but how can I construct a function?

Comment: By pulling the intersection of the first circle proportionately to the intersection with the second.